# Update image path in CKEditor after being received from FileManager

Tags: file, configuration, upload, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor with Fileman as the file manager for handeling file uploads. Everything works perfectly fine on my local host and there is only a small problem on the production environment which I haven't been able to solve by playing around with the configuration.

I'm able to upload, edit, delete and select files in Fileman as seen in the next picture.

[image]

However, after I select a file (a picture) for example, a file path is returned in format of: **/www/path/to/image.jpg.**.

The problem is that the "www" part of the path is not visible online and the right path to be returned by the editor should be just **/path/to/image.jpg**.

Example of the path returned by Fileman:

[image]

Does anybody know how to force ckeditor or fileman to use just the publicly visible directory structure? Thank you!

Comment: I Think this problem related to fileman only, because files & filePath Provided by **fileman**  for ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this problem:

- Set the following properties according the documentation: [`FILES_ROOT`](http://www.roxyfileman.com/install?#FILES_ROOT) and [`RETURN_URL_PREFIX`](http://www.roxyfileman.com/install?#RETURN_URL_PREFIX)

**Not recommended:**

- Create a soft link to your `www` folder (on linux for example ln -s /www /www/www)

The second solution could lead to some serious security problems and needs your server to be able to follow symlinks [Apache2 example](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html)

**EDIT**: I missed your problem first... The solution (in fileman): **"The path must be absolute from your *site root*!"** update your settings according to this and it will work fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. However, FILES_ROOT option only determines the upload folder location, which works fine. The problem is with the value being returned by fileman. RETURN_URL_PREFIX does not help either, because the prefix it adds is added after the wrong base path mentioned in my question.

Comment: Added the real solution to the question.

Answer (score -1):

As I haven't found a better solution, what turned out to work was to set .htaccess to redirect the /www/... path to /... and. It is possible to use this until there is a more elegant solution available.